# LDAP authentication configuration for multiple OU

Tags: jenkins, ldap

I am trying to get all our organization users to login using their LDAP domain credentials to Jenkins. 
With the options below, only users under 1 particular OU are able to login. I want to provide multiple OUs to search from.

Our Active Directory structure is as below:

*ca -> America -> Users -> actual user id*

*ca -> India -> Users -> actual user id*

Currently only users who are part of the America OU are able to login successfully to the application. I want users from both America and India OUs to be able to login successfully. 
I thought changing both User search base and Group search base as 'OU=Users,OU=America|OU=India' would work. But that fails for everybody. I tried replacing '|' with ','. But that did not help. 
Please provide suggestions or the right options to use. This is a blocker for our Jenkins implementation.

*root DN
DC=ca,DC=com
allow blank root DN
Not checked
User search base
OU=Users,OU=America
User search filter
sAMAccountName={0}
Group search base
OU=Users,OU=America
Group search filter
sAMAccountName={0}
Group membership
Search for groups containing user (selected option)
Group membership filter 
Manager DN
CN=admin,OU=Role-Based,OU=America,DC=ca,DC=com
Display name LDAP attribute
sAMAccountName
Email address LDAP attribute
mail
Environment variables
com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout = 60000
com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout = 60000*

Comment: Did you finally find a solution for this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the Active Directory plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin) since you are configuring the DNs. Try installing the plugin. Then,

1. Go to Jenkins -> Configure Global Security -> Security Realm
2. Choose Active Directory.
3. If your Jenkins machine is in the same domain you want to authenticate against, go to next step. Otherwise, you have to specify the domain(s).
4. In Authorization, add both OUs.
5. Save, and try to login.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.